# universal reference in void foo(T<U>&& param)

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, forwarding-reference

Is it possible to make `void foo` take a universal reference instead of a rvalue reference in case of a template template parameter like in the following code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <int I>
struct s
{
    string str;
};

template <template<int> class T, int U>
void foo(T<U>&& param)
{
    cout << param.str << endl;
}

int main()
{
    s<5> thing;
    foo( thing );
}
```

I get the [following error](http://ideone.com/c2yKv5):

```
error: cannot bind 's<5>' lvalue to 's<5>&&'
```

Comment: No. A forwarding reference (the official name for so-called "universal reference") must be `T&&`, where `T` is a template type parameter that's being deduced.

Answer (score 2):

No, universal references rely on a template argument being deduced as an lvalue reference. `T` cannot be an lvalue reference in `T<U>&&`, so that doesn't work.

What can work is using `T&&`, and using SFINAE to require it to match some `T<U>`.

```
template <template<int> class T, int U>
void foo_helper(const volatile T<U>&);

template <template<int> class T, int U>
void foo_helper(const volatile T<U>&&);

template <typename T, typename = decltype(foo_helper(std::declval<T>()))>
void foo(T&& param)
{
  cout << param.str << endl;
}
```

If needed, you can also provide helper type traits if `foo` is meant to use your `T` or `U` directly.

Comment: This example showe how to use U in foo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cc2f28bf549bfbf

Comment: @MofX Since I've already got the `foo_helper`, I think it would be easier to use `typename Traits = decltype(foo_helper(std::declval<T>))`, and make `foo_helper` return `foo_traits<T, U>` (which would contain whatever `foo` needs).